# Problem installing Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit side by side with Vista by using a bootable USB drive. What now?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, multi-boot, partitioning

### What happened

I decided to install Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit side by side with Vista Home Premium (I guess on another partition) with a USB stick. I found instructions on how to do this here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

To create the bootable USB drive I had to download a program called **Unetbootin**. That process was simple enough. All I had to do was just choose the *disk image* option, select the **ubuntu-10.04-desktop-amd64.iso** image, make sure it recognizes my USB drive and then press OK. It takes only like a few minutes to create a working bootable USB drive.

Then I have to restart my computer, enter the BIOS, select my USB drive as the first boot drive, save options and continue with booting up. After this Ubuntu actually loads up. I think this is known as the **Live** version of Ubuntu so you can try it out before fully installing it. Any ways, on the Ubuntu 10.04 desktop I saw an installer. I click it and begin the installation process. Just so you know, I tried installing it 2 times. I will explain what happened each time:

1. The first time I tried installing Ubuntu 10.04 I got stuck at step 4 of 7. I remember selecting the last option in the window which was **Specify Partitions Manually (Advanced)** I made my partition for Ubuntu like 52 gigs. I clicked forward and a little pop up window appeared saying *Please Wait*. So the installation process stalled on this window so I closed out of it and quit the installation process.
2. So at this point I was worried because I had already selected the partition size and assumed it started making it. Since it stalled I had to quit out though. Anyways, once again I reached step 4 of 7 a decided to select the first option which is **Install them side by side choosing between them each startup**. I figured this was the safe way to go. I did that and the pop up window saying *Please Wait* popped up again but lasted only like 10 seconds. Then I got to I guess step 6 where it asks you to enter your desired name and password. Did that and clicked forward. The Ubuntu 10.04 installation load screen appeared and the loading bar at the bottom started filling up. So I got to 83% and stalled during the *Importing other profile information* (I think it was called this. I had the option to do this during I think step 6) process. So at this point I decided to get stop the installation process. I was getting very nervous.

I tried to restart the computer but all that happened was that Ubuntu restarted. I finally got the computer to restart. I was pretty sure I had screwed something up big time by this point. As my computer was restarting I entered BIOS again and switched back to it booting from my main hard drive containing Vista. Saved it and continued the boot process. My worst fears were confirmed as Vista would not boot up. I mean I saw the little Microsoft Windows choppy animated green loading bar at the bottom of the screen and then boom! It decided to restart. When it restarted I had the option to run a memory test check to see if there was anything that needed to be repaired. That took like 20 minutes and at the end I saw that I did indeed have to repair something. I had to go through 2 repair processes. After each I had to restart the computer. The 2nd time it went through the repair process it said that it could not fully repair the damage. I was scared and restarted but Vista did load up. I got to my desktop and saw a message saying something like *Repairs have been made, Please restart for changes to take effect* I noticed that some Notification icons were missing and I could not hear volume in a video. Things were a bit funky. So I did restart and here I am.

---

### Now what?!

So since I got back into Vista and thankfully have a working Internet connection I am trying to find answers to my problem (that is why I am writing this post). I am scared that I have partioned my hard drive 2 times after researching *Installing Ubuntu 10.04* and seeing this post

http://techie-buzz.com/foss/ubuntu-10-04-lts-installation-guide.html

The author shows screen shots of installing Ubuntu 10.04. He shows the image of step 4 of 7  with a caption at the bottom. I will recreate it below:

---

[image]

**Select a partitioning option. Unless you want to format all the hard drive and install Ubuntu afresh, select the last option and proceed.**

---

### Questions

1. If I have indeed partitioned my HD 2 times (which I am sure it is), how do I get to a point where I can see all my bad, unfinished Ubuntu partitions and get rid of them? How do I clean this big mess up?
2. How can I ensure that this mess will not happen next time I try installing Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam,

there is now an application built into the Ubuntu ISO called 'wubi.exe' that lets you use Ubuntu without needing to partition your drive.  It will allow you to select that you want to load Ubuntu upon bootup.

As far as your extra partitions go, while booted to windows, right-click over "(my) computer" and click "manage".  In the window that opens, select "disk management" and you will be able to delete your extra partitions.  You may then merge them or leave them free for another attempt at installation.

Answer (score 2):

"How can I ensure that this mess will not happen next time I try installing Ubuntu 10.04?"

Install it [in a virtual machine](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/) or use [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/).